# change settings in Apache2 so that directories are listed by default for a page that contains no code?

Tags: sql-server, lamp

By defualt all pages left codless, but existing in a directory within the OS file systems accessable by the Apache server are automaticaly converted into site directorys, and list all URL's or other directorys with in their home directorys. Recently I switched the location of where apache loads index.html from, by defualt it was located in /var/www/html and now it resides in /var/www/AJC/html. My site loads fine, however upon doing this the server will no longer load the site directory for pages left codless.

Question #1) Does anyone know how to change the apache settings so it will load the contents of the home directory for the page being loaded (useally a list of urls, like a tree map for the website) for blank pages? 
Question #2) I was also wondering if PHP could access data from the server not in a sql-DB. Like can i some how get directory information passed through a superglobal?

Question 1 is what I really need to know, but any input/info on Question 2 would be nice to just know as far as grasping the capabilities and limits ofr PHP for someone newer to this language.

Answer (score 0):

Apache directory listing, use `Options +Indexes`:

```
  <Directory "/var/www/html/">
        Options ++Indexes
  </Directory>
```

PHP list contents of a directory:

```
$files = scandir(__DIR__);
foreach ($files as $f)
    print $f . PHP_EOL;
```